# Красивый вывод в консоль colorama на всю ширину консоли, а не на длину строки

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

```
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored

init()

print (colored('Hello World!', 'green','on_white'))
print (colored('Hi!', 'green', 'on_white'))
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы фон('on_white') строки был на всю ширину консоли, а не на длину строки?

Comment: Напечатать пробелы там где хотите разукрашку.

Answer (score 1):

Отформатировать строку по ширине консоли (в стандартной библиотеке Python - 79 символов)

```
print (colored('{0:{width}}'.format('Hello World!', width = 79), 'green','on_white'))
print (colored('{0:{width}}'.format('Hi!', width = 79), 'green', 'on_white'))
```

Comment: размер консоли это не константа, к примеру, в Питоне 3: `shutil.get_terminal_size()`. Можно посмотреть как реализовано и для Питона 2 выполнить аналог.